# Should a InitialDirContext object be closed explicitly everytime?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

There is an application that talks to LDAP on a need basis for several operations like user info fetch, list of users, list of groups, email ids etc. Every time a request has to be made an InitialDirContext object is created and used as follows.

`Properties ldapProperties = new Properties();
ldapProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
ldapProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://serv:636");
ldapProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
ldapProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
ldapProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
ldapProperties.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "tokenGroups");
InitialDirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(ldapProperties);
ctx.search(....);`

Should this "ctx" object be closed using the close() method?

If its not closed and there are multiple  **new InitialDirContext()** creations will the old ones be automatically closed?

If it was just an internal object it will be garbage collected but what about this connection object?

Answer (score 0):

No reason to close the context object each time. 
You should be aware that it would be possible that the server (or some network device like a Load balancer proxy) would close the connection and then you may need to reinitialize the connection.

We have some [Example JNDI solutions](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/dba1d74d172f/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/?at=master) you may find helpful.

-jim

Comment: Jim, thank you. I went through the examples. In my current code, the context object is not closed. And a new one is initialized whenever there is a need to communicate to LDAPS. 

One thing I noticed in the examples is that the "keystore" is explicitly being specified. Is this a must? I have the certificate imported into JRE and dont see the SSLHandshake anymore so I did not specify the keystore.

@ What parameter on the server side should I be looking for to see if its the server that is closing the connection? (I see an intermittent connection reset error when communicating to LDAPS)